# What is the probability of flipping at least 3 heads or 3 tails in a row over the course of 10 flips?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, permutations

I want to find the chance of a **streak** of 3 or more of the same side occurring within 10 flips.

My idea:

```
Number of favorable outcomes / Number of possible outcomes
Number of favorable outcomes / 2^10
```

To find the number of favorable outcomes:

First, I find all possibilities of the 7 non-streaking flips:

```
2^7
```

Then I find all the possibilities of the streak of 3 flips:

```
It could be HEADS or TAILS
It could be in any of the 8 positions between the non-streaking flips
2 sides * 8 positions = 16
```

My wrong answer:

```
2^7*16 / 2^10 = 2
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: "First, I find all possibilities of the 7 non-streaking flips: $2^7$"  Why on earth do you think that?  $2^7$ flips will include $HHHHHHH$ to $TTTTTTT$ which clearly include streaks.  And even if you managed to find the number of seven flips that have no streak of three how does that help you find the streaks as could be $2$ followed by the streak of $3$ for a streak of 5.  And you can have a streak of more than $6$ which would require of "7 nonstreaking" *have* a streak of 6.  I think you need to start over.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to work out the complementary probability, that all streaks
have length at most $2$. Then there will be $j$ streaks of length $2$
and $10-2j$ streaks of length $1$, $10-j$ streaks altogether. Here $0\le j\le 5$. Out of the $10-j$ streaks you must choose $j$ to have length $2$
and you can choose to start with a head or tail. Therefore there are
$$2\binom{10-j}j$$
sequences with $10-2j$ streaks of length $1$ and $j$ of length $2$.
The probability you seek is then
$$1-\frac1{2^9}\sum_{j=0}^5\binom{10-j}j.$$

Answer (score -1):

Let ${\mathscr{S}}_{n}$ be the set of sequences of $n$
flips that don't contain a streak of $3$. We are going
to compute $\left|{\mathscr{S}}_{n}\right|$ by induction on $n$. First
note that ${\mathscr{S}}_{1} = \left\{H , T\right\}$ and
${\mathscr{S}}_{2} = \left\{H H , H T , T H , T T\right\}$, so that
$\left|{\mathscr{S}}_{1}\right| = 2$ and $\left|{\mathscr{S}}_{2}\right| = 4$.

In order to give an induction formula, we partition

$${\mathscr{S}}_{n} = {\mathscr{V}}_{n} \cup  {\mathscr{W}}_{n}$$

where ${\mathscr{W}}_{n}$ is the subset of sequences that end with a double
streak, such as $H H$, and ${\mathscr{V}}_{n}$ is the set of sequences
that don't end with a double streak. Obviously, $\left|{\mathscr{V}}_{2}\right| = 2$
and $\left|{\mathscr{W}}_{2}\right| = 2$.

We create elements of ${\mathscr{S}}_{n+1}$ by appending a flip to an element
$s \in  {\mathscr{S}}_{n}$. If $s \in  {\mathscr{W}}_{n}$, there is only
one way to complete it without creating a streak of $3$ and
the result an element of ${\mathscr{V}}_{n+1}$. If $s \in  {\mathscr{V}}_{n}$, there
are two ways to complete it, one way creates an element of ${\mathscr{V}}_{n+1}$,
the other way creates an element of ${\mathscr{W}}_{n+1}$.

It follows that we have the following induction relations

$$\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}\left|{\mathscr{V}}_{n+1}\right|&=&\left|{\mathscr{V}}_{n}\right|+\left|{\mathscr{W}}_{n}\right|\\
\left|{\mathscr{W}}_{n+1}\right|&=&\left|{\mathscr{V}}_{n}\right|
\end{array}\right.$$

It is now obvious by induction that $\left|{\mathscr{V}}_{n}\right| = 2 {F}_{n}$ and
$\left|{\mathscr{W}}_{n}\right| = 2 {F}_{n-1}$, where ${F}_{n}$ is the
$n$th [Fibonacci number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number). Indeed the result is true when
$n = 2$ and the relation ${F}_{n+1} = {F}_{n}+{F}_{n-1}$ ensures
the induction.
The conclusion is that

$$\boxed{\left|{\mathscr{S}}_{n}\right| = \left|{\mathscr{V}}_{n}\right|+\left|{\mathscr{W}}_{n}\right| = 2 {F}_{n}+2 {F}_{n-1} = 2 {F}_{n+1}}$$

In particular, $\left|{\mathscr{S}}_{10}\right| = 2\times{F}_{11} = 178$.

It follows that the required probability is

$$1-\frac{178}{{2}^{10}} = \frac{423}{512}$$

Incidentally, combining this with @LordSharkTheUnknown's reasoning yields the conjectural result (which proof by induction looks easy).
$$
\boxed{\sum_{j\ \le\ n-j}\binom{n-j}{ j} = F_{n+1}}
$$
This formula is also given in the Wikipedia page about [binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).